# grunt fails, "cannot find module 'tmp'"

Tags: gruntjs, npm

I'm taking over an existing project. It contains a package.json and Gruntfile. According to the instructions [here](http://gruntjs.com/getting-started) I've run

```
npm install
```

after installing grunt-cli globally.

However, running grunt results in

```
$ grunt --env=production
Loading "compass.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'tmp'
Warning: Task "compass" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

Running with -v gives a traceback:

```
Loading "compass.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Cannot find module 'tmp'
>>     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
>>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
>>     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
>>     at require (module.js:380:17)
>>     at Object.exports.init (/..(path)../node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/tasks/lib/compass.js:4:13)
>>     at Object.module.exports (/..(path)../node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/tasks/compass.js:12:42)
>>     at loadTask (/..(path)../node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:325:10)
>>     at /..(path)../node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:361:7
>>     at Array.forEach (native)
>>     at loadTasks (/..(path)../node_modules/grunt/lib/grunt/task.js:360:11)
```

"..(path).." has been inserted by me replacing a long base path, it's the project's root.

After some further investigation, compass.js imports the 'tmp' module

```
  var tmp = require('tmp');
```

Who / what provides this module?

Comment: What is in Gruntfile?

Comment: Too much, 440 lines of code and I suspect the problem is actually with compass.js' import of 'tmp', see update.

Answer (score 10):

Removing node_modules (which was under source control, to my suprise) and running

```
npm cache clean
npm install
```

solved this problem.

Answer (score 2):

As of npm@5, the npm cache self-heals from corruption issues and data extracted from the cache is guaranteed to be valid. If you want to make sure everything is consistent, use `npm cache verify` instead.

If you want to force clean, try `npm cache clean --force` after that run `npm cache verify`